# Hyper-V vs Virutalbox on hardware with SSD

Tags: virtualization, hyper-v, virtualbox

We plan to have a powerful CPU along with SSD with Host OS - Windows 7 or 8.1 Enterprise

This PC will have VM's running Windows 7. Idea is to use VirtualBox for creating the Guest OS and boot them during OS boot

The host CPU has SSD and we would like us the potential of the host

For this will Virutual box serves better or Hyper-V ?

Comment: This site is for professional sysadmins as we make very clear when you sign up - this isn't a professional setup in any way.

Comment: Yes, it's in our help pages that we put in front of you when you sign up

Comment: Sorry! my bad...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hyper-V will be better, because it's a Type-1 hypervisor (runs directly on the hardware) compared to VirtualBox's being a Type-2 hyervisor (runs on top of another OS).

It will have fewer layers, more control of scheduling hardware access between VMs.

It's also fitting to run a Microsoft hypervisor with Microsoft operating systems, as it will get updates through Windows update.

[Hyper-V appears to runs on top of the host OS, so why is it considered a native (type-1) hypervisor?](https://superuser.com/questions/836116/hyper-v-appears-to-runs-on-top-of-the-host-os-so-why-is-it-considered-a-native)

Comment: Thanks. I will first read the link you have provided as it seem to have some interesting insights