# Is Hyper-V role in Windows 10 Pro different from role in Windows Server?

Tags: windows, virtualization, hyper-v, hypervisor

As I understand it, when you enable Hyper-V role in Server 2008 and above, it will actually virtualize Server OS itself to run on top of Hyper-V.

Source:

- https://serverfault.com/questions/326844/is-hyper-v-a-real-hypervisor
- [Hyper-V appears to runs on top of the host OS, so why is it considered a native (type-1) hypervisor?](https://superuser.com/questions/836116/hyper-v-appears-to-runs-on-top-of-the-host-os-so-why-is-it-considered-a-native)

When I enable the Hyper-V role on Win 10 Pro, does the same thing happen?

Comment: They are not the same.

Answer (score 2):

In both cases (server and non-server Windows versions) hyper-v is installed as a type 1 hypervisor in between the hardware and the host OS; so in that sense the Host OS is converted to a virtual machine.

There are [differences in implementation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyperv_on_windows/about/hyperv_on_windows) between server and non-server versions however:

> Differences between Hyper-V on Windows and Hyper-V on Windows Server
>
> There are some features that work differently in Hyper-V on Windows
>   than they do in Hyper-V running on Windows Server.
>
> The memory management model is different for Hyper-V on Windows. On a
>   server, Hyper-V memory is managed with the assumption that only the
>   virtual machines are running on the server. In Hyper-V on Windows,
>   memory is managed with the expectation that most client machines are
>   running software on host in addition to running virtual machines. For
>   example, a developer might be running Visual Studio as well as several
>   virtual machines on the same computer.
>
> Hyper-V features available in Windows Server only
>
> There are some features included in Hyper-V on Windows Server that are
>   not included in Hyper-V on Windows. These include:
>
> Virtualizing GPUs using RemoteFX 
> Live migration of virtual machines
>   from one host to another
>  Hyper-V Replica
>  Virtual Fiber Channel
>  SR-IOV
>   networking
>  Shared .VHDX
>  Limitations
>
> Using virtualization does have limitations. Features or applications
>   that depend on specific hardware will not work well in a virtual
>   machine. For example, games or applications that require processing
>   with GPUs might not work well. Also, applications relying on sub-10ms
>   timers such as live music mixing applications or high precision times
>   could have issues running in a virtual machine.
>
> In addition, if you have Hyper-V enabled, those latency-sensitive,
>   high-precision applications may also have issues running in the host.
>   This is because with virtualization enabled, the host OS also runs on
>   top of the Hyper-V virtualization layer, just as guest operating
>   systems do. However, unlike guests, the host OS is special in that it
>   has direct access to all the hardware, which means that applications
>   with special hardware requirements can still run without issues in the
>   host OS.

Comment: They are referring to a server configuration typically running only virtual machines (clients) without a user session on the host OS. They are stating that as the assumption on which their memory usage model differences between server and windows are based. That's really a side note in the context of your question. In either OS version the host OS is a 'special' client of the hypervisor, with full HW access, but still running on top of the virtualization layer.

Comment: "In both cases (server and non-server Windows versions) hyper-v is installed as a type 1 hypervisor in between the hardware and the host OS" 

Are you sure about this? I looked for a way to detect if Windows is running virtualized and found this - 'wmic baseboard get manufacturer,product', this should show Microsoft as the oem when running as guest. I enabled the Hyper-V role on my Windows 10 Pro pc, and this command still shows Dell as before. Also I've read that Hyper-V doesn't passthru SMART data as it uses its own disk driver, but that is not happening either. I have raw disk access.

Comment: Also do you have a source which says that even on Win 10 enabling Hyper-V virtualizes the OS? I'll be very happy if that indeed is the case.

Comment: In the link I provided (and the quoted excerpt from it) it explicitly states that. It's from MS...

Comment: Sorry if I missed it, but the msdn link only talks about the differences and specifically the memory management, which you quoted here. I don't see anything related to 'in both cases its installed as a type 1 hypervisor and host OS is converted to a VM'.