# wrong hardware virtualization support message?

Tags: bios, virtualization, hyper-v, hardware-virtualization

I have a lenovo Z570 laptop running windows 10 64-bit. My processor (i5-2430m) + bios offer support to virtualization.

however if I **enable** "*Intel virtualization*" option in bios:

- hyper-V works fine.
- [securable](https://www.grc.com/securable.htm) shows that hardware virtualization is **not supported**.
- [coreinfo](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx) shows VMX not available but HYPERVISOR available

And if I **disable** "*Intel virtualization*" option in bios:

- Hyper-V shows error message that hypervisor is not running if I try to start  a guest.
- [securable](https://www.grc.com/securable.htm) shows that hardware virtualization is **supported**.
- [coreinfo](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx) shows VMX available but HYPERVISOR not available.

Is this normal or is there any problem with my bios/windows? If it's normal please explain what is actually happening!

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Using a software that was updated the last time almost a decade ago might not be your best option to figure out whenever your CPU supports virtualization. What is EMX supposed to stand for? It's not listed in the [help for coreinfo](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/cc835722.aspx)? Do you have any problems with running Hyper-V? If not, as it is the only real virtualization you've done, there doesn't seem to be any problem?

Comment: Sorry man that was VMX! Yes I don't have any problem running hyper-V, but opposing statements given by securable, coreinfo , etc. is what that really  bugs me.

Comment: For secureable it looks like you should get more information if you click on the yes/no. Right now I would assume it's just a bit dated. For coreinfo it could be that it's reporting the correct thing from its perspective. Have a look at [Hyper-V appears to runs on top of the host OS, so why is it considered a native (type-1) hypervisor?](http://superuser.com/questions/836116/hyper-v-appears-to-runs-on-top-of-the-host-os-so-why-is-it-considered-a-native).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys I finally understood the reason for my problems after reading this [answer](https://superuser.com/a/836123/678666)

After enabling the *Intel Virtualization* in bios windows 10 host now acts like a VM running from hypervisor that is linked with bios. So securable and coreinfo shows that VMX not available as it is already running in a VM.

Answer (score 2):

Get this [Id utility from intel](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/7838).
Check if Execute Disable Bit and Enhanced Halt State are enabled.

Note that **Intel's proprietary Virtualization Technology HAXM and Hyper-V cannot run at the same time**. Make sure "Hyper-V", a Windows feature, is not installed/enabled on your system. Hyper-V captures the VT virtualization capability of the CPU, so HAXM and Hyper-V cannot run at the same time.

Depending on what you want to accomplish either enable or disable Hyper-V at start-up using `bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off/auto`.

Comment: This is slightly misleading since Hyper-V _uses_ Intel Virtualization Technology; the bold should probably say "Intel HAXM and Hyper-V"?

Comment: Agreed and updated, but HAXM / Hy-V was specified near the end of the paragraph.